# use .dir-locals.el to pick major mode

Tags: emacs, elisp

I want to use jinja2-mode for files ending ".html" when the variable `my:use-jinja-for-html-p` is non-nil.

I have the following files:

**.dir-locals.el**

```
((nil . ((my:use-jinja-for-html-p . t))))
```

**blah.html**

```
<html>
```

**.emacs**

```
(defvar my:use-jinja-for-html-p nil
  "Use `jinja2-mode' if non-nil, otherwise `html-mode'.
Primarily for use in .dir-locals.el")

(defun my:maybe-choose-jinja2-mode ()
  (when my:use-jinja-for-html-p
    (jinja2-mode)))

(add-hook 'html-mode-hook 'my:maybe-choose-jinja2-mode)
```

`my:maybe-choose-jinja2-mode` runs after html-mode, but uses the global value of `my:use-jinja-for-html-p` instead of the file-local value specified in `.dir-locals.el`.

Why doesn't `my:maybe-chose-jinja2-mode` use the file-local value?

**Answer for Completeness - see dupe for detail**

```
;; See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147060/ for explanation of
;; why we're creating a new hook.  tl;dr: wierd interaction between
;; `set-auto-mode' and `hack-local-variables'
(add-hook 'hack-local-variables-hook 'my:run-local-vars-mode-hook)
(defun my:run-local-vars-mode-hook ()
  "Run a hook for major-mode after processing local variables.
e.g. `python-mode-local-vars-hook',`emacs-lisp-mode-local-vars-hook'"
  (run-hooks (intern (format "%s-local-vars-hook" (symbol-name major-mode)))))

(add-hook 'html-mode-local-vars-hook 'my:maybe-choose-jinja2-mode)
```

Comment: What is `use-jinja-p`?  Did you mean to use `my:use-jinja-for-html-p`?

Comment: Yep, I simplified the code, but forgot to change that back.

Comment: And is your HTML file in the proper directory for the `.dir-locals.el` file to control it?

Comment: The files are in the same directory. If I run M-x eval-expression file-local-variables-alist in blah.html, I see that my:use-jinja-for-html-p is set to t