# Overwrite a `defcustom` with type `string` with a function that generates a string

Tags: variables, emacs

How do you overwrite a `defcustom` of `type: string` with a function that generates a string? Below a specific set-up is detailed:

**Current set-up**

In a [.dir-locals.el](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Directory-Local-Variables.html) file two variables are created `python-shell-virtualenv-root` and `python-pytest-executable`.

```lisp
((nil . ((eval . (let ((direnv-python ".direnv/python-3.7.2"))
                   (setq-local python-shell-virtualenv-root (expand-file-name direnv-python projectile-project-root)
                               python-pytest-executable (expand-file-name (concat direnv-python "/bin/pytest") projectile-project-root)))
         ))))
```

The snippet above builds the two variables using `direnv-python`.

**Preferred set-up**

Globally define the functions that build the two variables `python-shell-virtualenv-root` and `python-pytest-executable`, preferably in an [`init.el`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html). Then, in the `.dir-locals.el` define the `direnv-python` variable.

Then `python-shell-virtualenv-root` and `python-pytest-executable` should be created dynamically, using the `direnv-python` variable.

**Motivation**

The logic for creating `python-shell-virtualenv-root` and `python-pytest-executable` is the same for every project. The `direnv-python` is project specific. I would like to only specify the later per project.

**EDIT**

[1] `defvar` should be `defcustom`

Comment: `defvar` has no facility for type declarations. Did you perhaps mean `defcustom`? If so, please edit the question to clarify. Thx. If this is about a user option (`defcustom` variable) then try `M-x customize-option`. If the type you want isn't allowed by the variable definition (`defcustom`) then rethink your need. You can use your own `defcustom`, if you evaluate it before the usual one, but that might not be a good idea, as other code might depend on the declared types.

Comment: It should be `defcustom` indeed, updated accordingly. I think it is not possible to do this due to the type differences

Comment: As I said, *"You can use your own defcustom, if you evaluate it before the usual one, but that might not be a good idea, as other code might depend on the declared types."* IOW, the `defcustom` :type definition rules, and the first `defcustom` evaluated for the variable wins. Augment the `:type` in your own defcustom, to allow a value that's a function.

Comment: Yes, this allows me to change the `type` but - like you said - it is probably not a good idea because other code depends on it. You answered my question, but I asked the wrong question.

Comment: You can still ask the right question (as a separate question, please).

Answer (score 1):

@Drew answered the question in the comments. In short, you can define your own `defcustom` with the wanted `type` if you make sure it is evaluated before the already existing definition.

However, like Drew mentioned, it is probably not want you want to do, since other code expects the original `type` and therefore is likely to break.

**Preferred set-up** 
To get to the **preferred set-up** mentioned in the question, I did the following:

```lisp
;; In config.el

(defcustom python-projectile-environment-directory ".direnv/python-3.7.2"
  "The python environment within a projectile project"
  :type 'string
  :group 'python)

;; Run a hook after local vars are read
;; Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147060/how-can-i-access-directory-local-variables-in-my-major-mode-hooks
(defun run-local-vars-mode-hook ()
  "Run a hook for the major-mode after the local variables have been processed."
  (run-hooks (intern (concat (symbol-name major-mode) "-local-vars-hook"))))

(add-hook 'hack-local-variables-hook 'run-local-vars-mode-hook)

;; Set-up the python shell
(defun config/python-mode-shell-setup ()
  (message "project python environment is %s" python-projectile-environment-directory)
  (setq-local python-shell-virtualenv-root (expand-file-name python-projectile-environment-directory (projectile-project-root))
              python-pytest-executable (expand-file-name (concat python-projectile-environment-directory "/bin/pytest") (projectile-project-root))))

(add-hook 'python-mode-local-vars-hook 'config/python-mode-shell-setup)
```

The `run-local-vars-mode-hook` allows you to run a hook **after** the local variables are read (see mentioned link for more details). This was the missing link that allows the use of local variables in a hook.

After that the `config/python-mode-shell-setup` sets-up the python shell using the local variable `python-projectile-environment-directory`.

```lisp
;; .dir-locals.el

((python-mode . ((python-projectile-environment-directory . ".direnv/python-3.7.9"))))
```

If that local variable is not present, the default value of `defcustom` ".direnv/python-3.7.2" is used.