# Getting emacs M-; to produce // style comments

Tags: emacs

How do I change the style of comments for M-; (comment-dwim) when using c-mode?

I would like it to use comments preceeded by // instead of /* */ nesting.

Version:

```
GNU Emacs 23.2.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.20.1) of 2010-12-11 on brahms, modified by Debian
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The relevant vars are `comment-start` and `comment-end` so you can use this:

```
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook (lambda () (setq comment-start "//"
                                        comment-end   "")))
```

Comment: Works for PHP too :) I use this command to (un)comment the current line if nothing is selected : `(defun px-toggle-comments ()
  "If region is set, [un]comments it. Otherwise [un]comments current line."
  (interactive)
  (if (eq mark-active nil)
      (progn
        (beginning-of-line 1)
        (set-mark (point))
        (forward-line)
        (comment-dwim nil))
    (comment-dwim nil))
  (deactivate-mark))
`

Comment: In your cpp hook:
    (setq comment-start "/// ")
    (setq comment-end "")
    (setq comment-continue "/// ")

Comment: The space should usually be in the var `comment-padding`. Might explain why @Mike gets one.

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/info2www?(emacs)C%20Mode:

> C++ mode is like C mode, except that it understands C++ comment syntax
>   and certain other differences between C and C++.  It also has a
>   command `M-x fill-c++-comment', which fills a paragraph made of C++
>   comment lines.

So you can just add this line to your .emacs:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.[ch]\\'" . c++-mode))
```

Comment: I'm not sure. That would open his file in C++ mode which is different.

Comment: how different is it? Try it and see if it fits your needs.

Comment: If you want to open C files in c-mode and C++ files in c++-mode, that's been covered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312114

Comment: npoektop : For one, the C++ mode will have a different set of keywords that will have different syntax highlighting and indentation.