# Activate latex-mode for .tikz files in Emacs

Tags: emacs

How can I make latex-mode to apply to files with .tikz extension in Emacs? (I am using Auctex)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to tell emacs to open .h file in C++ mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312114/how-to-tell-emacs-to-open-h-file-in-c-mode)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run `M-x latex-mode` in the file buffer.  If you want to automatically do this for every file you visit add the following to `.emacs`,

```
 (setq auto-mode-alist
     (append
         '(("\\.tikz\\'" . latex-mode))
          auto-mode-alist))
```

`auto-mode-alist` is a list of file types and the mode to apply as you may have guessed.  You can run `C-h v auto-mode-alist` to get a description of the variable for your emacs.