# How do I activate "lisp mode" for cljs files in emacs?

Tags: emacs, clojure, syntax-highlighting, clojurescript, paredit

Currently emacs isn't turning on paredit and isn't using any syntax highlighting when I edit .cljs files. It does when I edit .clj files and I want it to treat .cljs similar.

What do I have to do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to tell emacs to open .h file in C++ mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312114/how-to-tell-emacs-to-open-h-file-in-c-mode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have everything working for clojure you can just turn `clojure-mode` on for the current buffer using

> M-x clojure-mode

If you want it turned on automatically you need to add an entry to the [Auto Mode AList](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoModeAlist). In my case, adding the following to `init.el` did the trick:

> (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\.cljs$" . clojure-mode))

After that you need to reload your `init.el` (`M-x load-file`) and re-open the file.