# Automatically load c++ mode for HPP and CPP files

Tags: emacs

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312114/how-to-tell-emacs-to-open-h-file-in-c-mode), but the accepted solution does not work for me. I still need to manually load c++-mode for indentation (!) (not syntax highlighting, however. But that worked before anyway) to be set to c++-mode. In my init I have this code:

```
(setq
 c-default-style "stroustrup"
 )

(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.cpp\\'" . c++-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.hpp\\'" . c++-mode))

(defun my-c++-mode-hook ()
  (setq c-basic-offset 4)
  (c-set-offset 'substatement-open 0))
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'my-c++-mode-hook)
```

and my entire init looks like this:

```
    (require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
         '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)

(setq gc-cons-threshold 100000000)
(setq inhibit-startup-message t)

(defalias 'yes-or-no-p 'y-or-n-p)

(defconst demo-packages
  '(anzu
    company
    duplicate-thing
    ;; ggtags
    ;; helm
    ;; helm-gtags
    ;; helm-projectile
    ;; helm-swoop
    ;; function-args
    clean-aindent-mode
    comment-dwim-2
    ;; dtrt-indent
    ws-butler
    ;; iedit
    yasnippet
    smartparens
    ;; projectile
    ;; volatile-highlights
    ;; undo-tree
    zygospore))

(defun install-packages ()
  "Install all required packages."
  (interactive)
  (unless package-archive-contents
    (package-refresh-contents))
  (dolist (package demo-packages)
    (unless (package-installed-p package)
      (package-install package))))

(install-packages)

;; this variables must be set before load helm-gtags
;; you can change to any prefix key of your choice
;; (setq helm-gtags-prefix-key "\C-cg")

(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/custom")

;; (require 'setup-helm)
;; (require 'setup-helm-gtags)
;; (require 'setup-ggtags)
(require 'setup-cedet)
(require 'setup-editing)

(windmove-default-keybindings)

;; function-args
;; (require 'function-args)
;; (fa-config-default)
;; (define-key c-mode-map  [(tab)] 'company-complete)
;; (define-key c++-mode-map  [(tab)] 'company-complete)

;; company
(require 'company)
(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'global-company-mode)
(delete 'company-semantic company-backends)
;; (define-key c-mode-map  [(tab)] 'company-complete)
;; (define-key c++-mode-map  [(tab)] 'company-complete)
;; (define-key c-mode-map  [(control tab)] 'company-complete)
(define-key c++-mode-map  [(control tab)] 'company-complete)

;; company-c-headers
(add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-c-headers)

;; hs-minor-mode for folding source code
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'hs-minor-mode)

;; Available C style:
;; “gnu”: The default style for GNU projects
;; “k&r”: What Kernighan and Ritchie, the authors of C used in their book
;; “bsd”: What BSD developers use, aka “Allman style” after Eric Allman.
;; “whitesmith”: Popularized by the examples that came with Whitesmiths C, an early commercial C compiler.
;; “stroustrup”: What Stroustrup, the author of C++ used in his book
;; “ellemtel”: Popular C++ coding standards as defined by “Programming in C++, Rules and Recommendations,” Erik Nyquist and Mats Henricson, Ellemtel
;; “linux”: What the Linux developers use for kernel development
;; “python”: What Python developers use for extension modules
;; “java”: The default style for java-mode (see below)
;; “user”: When you want to define your own style
(setq
 c-default-style "stroustrup"
 )

(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.cpp\\'" . c++-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.hpp\\'" . c++-mode))

(defun my-c++-mode-hook ()
  (setq c-basic-offset 4)
  (c-set-offset 'substatement-open 0))
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'my-c++-mode-hook)



(global-set-key (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent)  ; automatically indent when press RET

;; activate whitespace-mode to view all whitespace characters
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c w") 'whitespace-mode)

;; show unncessary whitespace that can mess up your diff
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook (lambda () (interactive) (setq show-trailing-whitespace 1)))

;; use space to indent by default
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)

;; set appearance of a tab that is represented by 4 spaces
(setq-default tab-width 4)

;; Compilation
(global-set-key (kbd "<f5>") (lambda ()
                               (interactive)
                               (setq-local compilation-read-command nil)
                               (call-interactively 'compile)))

;; setup GDB
(setq
 ;; use gdb-many-windows by default
 gdb-many-windows t

 ;; Non-nil means display source file containing the main routine at startup
 gdb-show-main t
 )

;; Package: clean-aindent-mode
(require 'clean-aindent-mode)
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'clean-aindent-mode)

;; Package: dtrt-indent
(require 'dtrt-indent)
(dtrt-indent-mode 1)

;; Package: ws-butler
(require 'ws-butler)
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'ws-butler-mode)

;; Package: yasnippet
(require 'yasnippet)
(yas-global-mode 1)

;; Package: smartparens
(require 'smartparens-config)
(setq sp-base-key-bindings 'paredit)
(setq sp-autoskip-closing-pair 'always)
(setq sp-hybrid-kill-entire-symbol nil)
(sp-use-paredit-bindings)

(show-smartparens-global-mode +1)
(smartparens-global-mode 1)

;; Package: projejctile
(require 'projectile)
(projectile-global-mode)
(setq projectile-enable-caching t)

;; (require 'helm-projectile)
;; (helm-projectile-on)
;; (setq projectile-completion-system 'helm)
;; (setq projectile-indexing-method 'alien)

;; Package zygospore
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x 1") 'zygospore-toggle-delete-other-windows)

(require 'ggtags)
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook
          (lambda ()
            (when (derived-mode-p 'c-mode 'c++-mode 'java-mode 'asm-mode)
              (ggtags-mode 1))))

(define-key ggtags-mode-map (kbd "C-c g s") 'ggtags-find-other-symbol)
(define-key ggtags-mode-map (kbd "C-c g h") 'ggtags-view-tag-history)
(define-key ggtags-mode-map (kbd "C-c g r") 'ggtags-find-reference)
(define-key ggtags-mode-map (kbd "C-c g f") 'ggtags-find-file)
(define-key ggtags-mode-map (kbd "C-c g c") 'ggtags-create-tags)
(define-key ggtags-mode-map (kbd "C-c g u") 'ggtags-update-tags)

(define-key ggtags-mode-map (kbd "M-,") 'pop-tag-mark)
```

I got it from here: http://tuhdo.github.io/c-ide.html

And currently I am altering it to fit my needs better.

Any idea what might be conflicting here, causing

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.cpp\\'" . c++-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.hpp\\'" . c++-mode))
```

not to work?

Comment: How about trying with **Emacs -Q** and just your two `auto-mode-alist` settings, and then if it works, recursively bisect your user-customizations by commenting stuff out and restarting Emacs until you find the culprit?

Comment: yea just basically did that and found the two causes. What does -Q do though? help says "quick". What is that supposed to mean?

Answer (score 0):

No idea why but commenting out

```
(require 'dtrt-indent)
(dtrt-indent-mode 1)
```

and

```
(require 'setup-editing)
```

fixed it.